# Plugins and how to assign urls to content

Tags: plugin-development, urls, slug

I'm Building a plugin for wordpress.

It has a few custom tables for the content.

A displays table contains the main content with title, description and a few other fields for content related to the display.
there are 2 other tables for images and videos which are linked to a display.

Now on the main site, i would like the url http://example.com/displays
to show a template page listing all the displays, a menu on the left listing all the displays and the display content on the right which links to each display i.e http://www.example.com/displays/displayname.

Can anyone point me to a good resource or explain what steps i would need to do this.

Comment: Before getting into an answer to your question, consider first if you can instead use custom post types / meta data / taxonomies to store your data, which will get you archive and singular URLs for free.

Comment: I had looked at custom post types, but prefer separating the plugin data from the standard wordpress post/pages.